# gVim doesn't recognize the Meta (Alt) Key in an imap after changing the encoding

Tags: vim

In order to edit html files, I have the following three imaps in a file that I source for filetype html:

```
imap <buffer> <M-[> &uuml;
imap <buffer> <M-;> &ouml;
imap <buffer> <M-'> &auml;
```

This works fine *until* I change the encoding of the html file with `set enc=utf-8`. Now, pressing Alt-[ for example gives me a **Û**.

Interestingly, after sourcing the *same* file again, it expands the imaps correctly.

This doesn't really make sense to me. So, why is this and how can I have a more constistent environment regarding imap and utf-8.

This is occuring with gVim 7.1 for Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the same problem listed here: https://superuser.com/questions/154491/utf-8-option-makes-alt-key-to-insert-accented-characters-in-vim-how-to-disable-i

I'd suggest putting `set encoding = utf-8` in your vimrc above your imap mappings, rather than turning it on for specific files.